# Режим "совместимый" IE

Tags: html, css, javascript

Я такой классный, сделал сайт, вроде во всех браузерах работает, но тут я зохжу в IE (любой) и у меня паника, вся вёрстка слетела, а тут я думаю дай зайду на mail.ru там всё хорошо. Затем открываю свой сайт нажимаю в IE f12 у меня стоит "Режим документов: совместимый", а на mail.ru режим документов стандартный.

Поясню ситуация для особо хитрых, режим "совместимости" я заметил у многих пользователей на автомате включен, на mail.ru стоит какая-то проверка от этого режима, не могу найти в интернете код примерно такого алгоритма - "если IE, то не открывать в режиме совместимый". Если многим это кажется смешным, зайдите на любой известный вам сайт после того, как зашли включите в IE через f12 режим документов совместимый, к примеру, даже mail.ru полностью слетает. Как поставить заглушку на этот "режим документов совместимый"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

подробнее тут http://www.xiper.net/manuals/html/meta-tags/http-equiv/x-UA-Compatible.html

Comment: А то я дурень в гугле не забил, не работает (

Comment: Куда бы я его не поставил, даже в нужное место, как написано в правилах он игнорируется

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

или

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">
```

Или другой DOCTYPE, который вам больше подходит, укажите в самом начале html-файла и IE не будет открывать вашу страницу в режиме совместимости.
Для принудительного выставления режима не смотря на доктайп, как уже выше писали, есть тег

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=версия" />
```

5 - Вынужденное переключение в режим IE5, доктайп при этом игнорируется.
7 - Вынужденное переключение в режим IE7, доктайп при этом игнорируется.
8 - Вынужденное переключение в режим IE8, доктайп при этом игнорируется.
9 - Вынужденное переключение в режим IE9, доктайп при этом игнорируется.
EmulateIE7 - При наличии доктайпа переключается в режим IE7, в противном случае в режим совместимости.
EmulateIE8 - При наличии доктайпа переключается в режим IE8, в противном случае в режим совместимости.
EmulateIE9 - При наличии доктайпа переключается в режим IE9, в противном случае в режим совместимости.
Edge - Устанавливает документ в наиболее новый доступный режим. Для версии 8.0 это режим IE8, для версии 9.0 это режим IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Вот хак для IE:
[`<!--If IE`](http://xpoint.ru/forums/internet/html_css/css/thread/40873.xhtml)